# How i can change the content of a UITableView when i press a button

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

i want change the content of a UITableView when i change a button, how i can do it?...i retrieve my information from Core Data, and when i press a button i want change the information in the tableview, i know the:

```
[self.tableview reloadData]
```

and in this way i give the information to the row:

```
NSManagedObject *name = [[self sortName] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text =  [[name valueForKey:@"firstName"] description]];
```

but my question is how i can give another array to my table view to retrieve information when i tap a button...i every where but i can't find an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information displayed in your table view cells are determined in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method.

In your code, it looks like this method references your array named *sortName*.

If you are retrieving your new data set into some other array, then you have to replace the contents of *sortName* with the contents of the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `sortName` array with the new contents after pressing the button. Than call reloadData..!?